# JavaFX display multiple gifs one by one

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, gif, animated-gif

I want to display different gifs one after another.
My idea was to dynamically change displaying gif which is wrapped into Image, using Timeline.
But I got an error:

> local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or
>   effectively final

Is there any solutions?

My code:

```
public class Task10 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox hbox5 = new HBox();

        VBox VBoxAll = new VBox();


        Image gifs[] = new Image[3];
        gifs[0] = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/img/L1.gif").toExternalForm());
        gifs[1] = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/img/L2.gif").toExternalForm());
        gifs[2] = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/img/L1.gif").toExternalForm());

        ImageView currentGif = new ImageView();


        Button localLoadButton = new Button("Start!");
        localLoadButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            show(currentGif, gifs);
        });

        hbox5.getChildren().addAll(currentGif, localLoadButton);

        VBoxAll.getChildren().addAll(hbox5);
        VBoxAll.setSpacing(15);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(VBoxAll);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 350);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void show(ImageView currentGif, Image[] gifs) {
        for (int i = 0; i<gifs.length; i++) {
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> { currentGif.setImage(gifs[i]); }),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> { currentGif.setImage(null); })
            );
            timeline.play();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please paste the whole class code (with imports). I've got a problem compiling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, local variables that are declared outside a lambda or anonymous class, but are used within said lambda or anonymous class, must be "effectively final". What that means is simply the local variable is never modified (i.e. reassigned). If a local variable could have the `final` keyword added to the declaration without causing a compilation error, the variable is effectively final.

In your code, you have the following:

```
public void show(ImageView currentGif, Image[] gifs) {
    for (int i = 0; i<gifs.length; i++) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> { currentGif.setImage(gifs[i]); }),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> { currentGif.setImage(null); })
        );
        timeline.play();
    }

}
```

You are referencing the local variable `i` inside the lambda (first `KeyFrame`). The problem is the `for` loop modifies the `i` (e.g. `i++`) which means the variable is not effectively final. A possible fix is to declare another variable inside the loop, assign it the value of `i`, then use that new (unchanging!) variable inside the lambda. However, that's not the only problem.

Your code is creating a separate `Timeline` for each element in the `gifs` array—in other words, one per loop. You also call `play` on each `Timeline` at the end of each iteration. This will result in multiple `Timeline`s all playing at once. As you might imagine, that won't do what you want. Instead, you should be creating a *single* `Timeline` and have each change of the `Image` be it's own `KeyFrame`. Something like the following:

```
public void show(ImageView view, Image[] gifs, Duration displayDuration) {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    Duration totalDelay = Duration.ZERO;
    for (Image gif : gifs) {
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(totalDelay, e -> view.setImage(gif));
        timeline.getFrames().add(frame);
        totalDelay = totalDelay.add(displayDuration);
    }
    timeline.getFrames().add(new KeyFrame(totalDelay, e -> view.setImage(null));

   timeline.play();
}
```

This will change the `Image` to the next `Image` in the array at `displayDuration` intervals.

If you're wondering why `gif` is allowed to be used inside the lambda—despite apparently being modified—this is because I used an "enhanced for loop". The variable of an enhanced for loop is treated differently than a regular `for` loop in that it's *initialized* each iteration. See [Enhanced 'for' loop and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340101/enhanced-for-loop-and-lambda-expressions) for more information.

Comment: I've read about lambda error. Your explanation was quite helpful! Thank you for the help!