# Thread safety of using reference of forEach loop in thread

Tags: java, thread-safety

Suppose I have these codes:

```
for(File file : fileList) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final File fileInThread = file;
            // doing some tasks which may take 5 sec to execute
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

What I want to know, is it thread-safe? Is there any possibility that, in first iteration, I am expecting the file of the first iteration, but it is initialized by a file of any other iteration of the loop? In that case, what can I do to handle this situation?

I need to send each file to a different thread. For each file, one thread will be created. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I have read this thread as well... [Enhanced 'for' loop and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340101/enhanced-for-loop-and-lambda-expressions) This question is totally different from my one.

Comment: You'll have each file in a different thread with this code. Just you can't be sure that the first file will be processed before the second one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enhanced 'for' loop and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340101/enhanced-for-loop-and-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Short answer: that `file` variable in your `for` loop is _effectively final_, so there's no chance of the value in your inner Runnable being changed by another thread.

Comment: @dnault, no it isn't. Just read that thread and this one as well.

Comment: it is not the case of final or effectively final. See the answer, I hope you will get it. And give a suggestion if there is anything to add. @dnault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens on each iteration of your `for(...)` loop:

1. The local variable `file` is assigned to refer to the next item in the given `fileList`.
2. The lambda expression creates a new instance of an anonymous, `Runnable` class, and the lambda *captures* the value of the `file` variable.
3. A new `Thread()` is created and started, using the anonymous `Runnable` object as its delegate.

On each subsequent iteration of the loop, a *different* instance of the anonymous class is created and each of those instances captures a *different* value of `file`.

When those threads run, each anonymous `Runnable` object, will have its own, distinct captured value for `file`.

---

The declaration, `final File fileInThread = file;` is not necessary.  When the `run()` method gets called for each of the different anonymous objects, `file` will refer to the *captured value*, which will be a different member of the list in each thread.

The `final fileInThread` variable will simply be another name for the same `File` instance that `file` refers to.  Again, *different* in each of the threads.

---

**D'Oh!** I said "lambda" in my description above, but the actual argument of the `Thread()` constructor is not a lambda expression. It's an instantiation of an anonymous inner class. Similar idea, but it uses an older, more verbose syntax.

Comment: One question.. do the variables declared outside of the anonymous class and uses in the anonymous class, become field variables of the anonymous class?

Comment: Otherwise, how can the run() remember which file is used for this thread? I am saying this, as iteration is going on, file is referring to different files.  If starting thread takes times, in second iteration first thread can start working.

Comment: @Mukit09, Yes. When you see `file` inside the `run()` method, that refers to an implicit field of the anonymous inner class. The field is initialized to have the same value as the `file` local variable that is declared in the `for(...)` loop.