# How to pass parameter in Supplier function with method reference operator(::)

Tags: java

Sorry, it seems to be very basic in functional programming but I am not getting this idea. Actually I have a method in my code which consumes a method and another param as a parameter.

```
private <R> CompletableFuture<R> retryRequest(Supplier<CompletableFuture<R>> supplier, int maxRetries)
```

I want to call this function and pass another method(anOtherMethod) which taking one integer parameter:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> retry = this.retryRequest(this:: anOtherMethod, 2);
```

Not getting this how I can call this retryRequest and give anOtherMethod(123)?

I know it can work like this:

```
   CompletableFuture<Boolean> retry = this.retryRequest(()-> anOtherMethod(123), 2);
```

Comment: It's correct, the only way is to call `retryRequest(()-> anOtherMethod(123), 2);` - it will be an anonymous Supplier `() -> xxx` which returns result of a closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot instantiate a lambda with a specific captured value like `123` in the pure method reference variant.**. You need to write the explicit lambda version with arrow, if you want to pass captured values other than the instance to execute the method on. Read more on capturing values in lambdas in this answer: [Enhanced 'for' loop and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340101/enhanced-for-loop-and-lambda-expressions/54340184#54340184)

The only exception is an object, which itself becomes the first parameter.
Assume a signature that expects a Consumer of a String:

```java
public void something(Consumer<String> job) {
...
```

The above signature will enable you to write the following calls:

```java
String myString = " Hey Jack ";
something(myString::trim);
something(s -> s.trim());
```

Both do the same, and this is maybe unintuitive, because one takes an argument (the instance reference `myString`) and one seem not to (but it actually does, too). This works, because the compiler tries two possible resolutions for a lambda method reference (the above version with `::`). On one hand, the compiler can apply signatures, as if the called method did not have any parameters, and none need passing. This is the case for `myString.trim`. But the compiler will also check, whether there is a static method `String.trim(myString)` (which luckiely there is not). If you wanted to call a static method without any parameters, then you'd have to call the class identifier with the function reference like so:

```java
something(String::trim); // this version of trim does not exist.
```

This is sometimes even a problem, because if a class offers a static version of a method and an instance-related one, you get ambiguity:

```java
public void somethingElse(Function<Integer, String> transformation) {...}

// This will not compile:
somethingElse(Integer::toString);
```

The above example will not compile, because the `toString` method exists twice, once as static `Integer.toString(someInt)` and once as instance related `someInteger.toString()`.